# input id starts with a string which is variabe

Tags: javascript

I want the input id starts with a string which is variable, the following code doesn't work

```
  var st="F" + pi + "_";
  $(':input[id^=st]').val($x(ti).value);
```

Comment: Unlike bash or PHP, JavaScript does not have any sort of variable interpolation in strings (beyond escape sequences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable into the string here.

```
$(':input[id^='+st+']').val($x(ti).value);
              ^^^^^^
```